# Optimizing grid connections with python

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have the following situation:

(1) I have a large grid. By some conditions I want to further observe specific points/cells in this grid. Each cell has an `ID` and coordinates `X`, `Y` seperately. So in this case lets observe one cell only - marked C on the image, that is located on the edge of the grid. By some formula I can get all the neighbouring cells of the first order (marked 1 on the image) and the second order (marked 2 on the image).

(2) With a further condition I identify some cells in the neighbouring cells and are marked in orange on the second image. What I want to do is to connect all orange cells with each other by optimizing the distances and takih into account only `min()` distances. My first attempt was to observe cells only by calculating the distances to cells of the lower order. So when looking at cells in neighbours cells 2, i'm looking at the cells in 1 only. The solution of connections is presented on image 2, but it's not optimal, since the ideal solution would compare the distances of all cells and not only of the cells of the lower neighbour order. By doing this, i'm getting the situation presented on image 3. And the problem is that the cells are of course not connected to the centre. What to do?

[image]

The current code is:

`CO` - list of centre points.

`data` - df all all ID's with X,Y values

```
CO_list = CO['ID'].tolist()

neighbor100 = []
for p in IskanjeCO_list:
    d = get_neighbors100k2(p, len(data)) #function that finds the ID's of neighbours of the first order
    neighbor100.append(d)

neighbor200 = []
for p in IskanjeCO_list:
    d = get_neighbors200k2(p, len(data)) #function that finds the ID's of neighbours of the second order
    neighbor200.append(d)

flat100 = []
for i in neighbor100:
  for j in i:
    flat100.append(j)

flat200 = []
for i in neighbor200:
  for j in i:
    flat200.append(j)

neighbors100 = flat100
neighbors200 = flat200

data_sosedi100 = data.iloc[flat100,].reset_index(drop=True)
data_sosedi200 = data.iloc[flat200,].reset_index(drop=True)

dist200 = []

for b in flat200:
    d = ((pd.DataFrame((data_sosedi100['X']* - data.iloc[b,]['X'])**2
         + (data_sosedi100['Y'] - data.iloc[b,]['Y'])**2 )**0.5)).sum(1)
    dist200.append(d.min())

data_sosedi200['dist'] = dist200

data_sosedi200['id'] = None
for e in CO_list:
    data_sosedi200.loc[data_sosedi200['FID_2'].isin((get_neighbors200k2(e, len(data)))),'id'] = e
```

Do you have any suggestion how to optimize this a bit further? I hope i presented the whole image. If needed, I'll clarify further. If you see a part of the code, where i'd be able to furher optimize this loop, i'd be very grateful!

Comment: this reminds me of some path finding algorithms, how complex could the grid be ? Are there situations where one and only one path would be correct and sometimes the minimum distance is not optimal and could lead to a dead-end ?

Comment: If we're looking at min distances only, you come to dead-end as seen on figure 3, since it's not connected to the C. I'm trying to a find "a trick" to ensure connectivity. I assume there can be situation where different paths can give the same result, that is - lenght of the entire path.

Comment: how do you choose your starting point ? Also where did you start in figure 3 to end up with such a shape ?

Comment: You always start in the centre (cell C on image 1). Then you look at first round of neigbors (cells 1 on image 1) and connect them by shortest distance to cell C. Going further - this is when you get to dilemma. You must connect cell that are neighbors of 2nd order (cells 2 on image 1) to either minimal distances the cells in neighbors cells of the 1st order and C - you get image 2  either to cells with min distance to all cells (neighbor cells 1, 2 and C) and you get image 3.

Comment: with your second analogy I don't see how cell 1 at coordinates (1,1) would not pick up cell 2 at coordinates (1,2) as the closest neighboring element. If you started at center (0,0) then you picked up (1,1) why not pick up (2,1) if you are looking at tall neighboring cells (C,1,2). Why is there a separate line that starts/ends at (1,2) / (2,0)

Comment: if C is (0,0).. all orange cells must be connected to the C. On image 2, cells that are neighbors of 2nd order, are connected by min distance to cells of the 1st order only. This is why e.g. (2,0) is connected to (1,1) and not (2,1) - image 2. If i'd connected them to min distances between all orange cells, than (2,0) and (2,1) would be connected (image 3).

Comment: One way to approach this although it's limited: 1- Find the 2 nodes furthest to the center, in this case (-2,1) and (2,3). 2- Start at each and check all neighboring elements that are viable options (in orange). 3- Pick always the neighboring element that is furthest away from center but still within list. 4- Add it to another list as non viable element to pick again. 5- Start from new picked element and the choose again a viable neighbor that is furthest from the center. 6- Repeat until you reach the center. 7- Do for both sides. 8 Append Paths.

Comment: Following this logic, let's say one of your starting points is (2,2) -> viable options are: (1,2) - (2,1) - (1,1). Since (1,1)  is the closest it won't be picked you are left (1,2) or (2,1) they have same distance from the center so both are good picks. Assuming we go with (1,2). From there the following neighboring viable elements are: (1,1) - (2,1) and we pick (2,1) because it is the furthest from the center.

Comment: I understand the logic. Thank you. I hope i'll be able to write the code properly :)

Comment: following through the 2 paths would look like: (2,2) -> (1,2) -> (2,1) -> (2,0) -> (1,1)-> (0,0) || (-2,1) -> (-2,0) -> (-1,0) -> (0,0). This will fail however if after (2,2) you go to (2,1) because you will run to a dead-end. But it wouldn't fail if you started at (-2,1) and (2,0).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182727/discussion-between-energymax-and-hadi-farah).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I defined the points manually to work with:
    import numpy as np
    from operator import itemgetter, attrgetter

```
nodes = [[-2,1], [-2,0], [-1,0], [0,0], [1,1], [2,1], [2,0], [1,2], [2,2]]
center = [0,0]

def find_neighbor(node):
    n=[]
    for i in range(-1,2):
        for j in range(-1,2):
            if not (i ==0 and j ==0):
                n.append([node[0]+i,node[1]+j])
    return [N for N in n if N in nodes]

def distance_to_center(node):
    return np.sqrt(node[0]**2+node[1]**2)

def distance_between_two_nodes(node1, node2):
    return np.sqrt((node1[0]-node2[0])**2+(node1[1]-node2[1])**2)

def next_node_closest_to_center(node):
    min = distance_to_center(node)
    next_node = node
    for n in find_neighbor(node):
        if distance_to_center(n) < min:
            min = distance_to_center(n)
            next_node = n
    return next_node, min

def get_path_to_center(node):
    node_path = [node]
    distance = 0.
    while node!= center:
        new_node = next_node_closest_to_center(node)[0]
        distance += distance_between_two_nodes(node, new_node)
        node_path.append(new_node)
        node=new_node

    return node_path,distance

def furthest_nodes_from_center(nodes):
    max = 0.
    for n in nodes:
        if get_path_to_center(n)[1] > max:
            furthest_nodes_pathwise = []
            max = get_path_to_center(n)[1]
            furthest_nodes_pathwise.append(n)
        elif get_path_to_center(n)[1] == max:
            furthest_nodes_pathwise.append(n)
    return furthest_nodes_pathwise

def farthest_node_from_center(nodes):
    max = 0.
    farthest_node = center
    for n in nodes:
        if distance_to_center(n) > max:
            max = distance_to_center(n)
            farthest_node = n
    return farthest_node

def closest_node_to_center(nodes):
    min = distance_to_center(farthest_node_from_center(nodes))
    for n in nodes:
        if distance_to_center(n) < min:
            min = distance_to_center(n)
            closest_node = n
    return closest_node

def closest_node_center_with_furthest_distance(node_selection):
    if len(node_selection) == 1:
        return node_selection[0]
    else:
        return closest_node_to_center(node_selection)


print(closest_node_center_with_furthest_distance(furthest_nodes_from_center(nodes)))
```

**Output:**

```
[2, 0]
[Finished in 0.266s]
```

By running on all nodes I can now determine that the furthest node away path-wise but still closest to the center distance wise is `[2,0]` and not `[2,2]`. So we start from there. To find the one on the other side just split the data like I said into negative x values and positive. if you run it over a list of only the negative x value cells you will get `[-2,1]`

Now that you have your 2 starting cells `[2,0]` and `[-2,1]` I will leave you to figure out the algorithm to navigate to the center passing by all cells using the steps in my comments (you can now skip step 1 because this is the answer posted)

Comment: if you have questions feel free to ask!